# Select dropdown with onChange event and Search functionality

Tags: select, search

I have a requirement of having redirected to a link on clicking an option from select dropdown for this have used this code and it works fine

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Germany</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Taiwan</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Singapore</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Mexico</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">UK</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">USA</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">India</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Vietnam</option>
</select>
```

Now my client cameup with additional requirement to have search field in select field so that users can search the country name so for that I used `selectize` function and changed the above code to

```
 <select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Germany</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Taiwan</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Singapore</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Mexico</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">UK</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">USA</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">India</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Vietnam</option>
  </select>

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select').selectize({
      sortField: 'text'
  });
```

});

But only the first option being shown, looks like there is some conflict happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But only the first option being shown, looks like there is some
> conflict happening

Yes, there is.

The [documentation](https://selectize.dev/docs/usage) says, "*Each object must have a property with a **unique value** to identify the option; the `valueField` setting defines the property name*", where "object" refers to an option in your menu.

But your `option`s all have the same `value`, which is `https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/`, therefore only the first one is shown.

So just ensure the value is unique and the issue would be gone. See example below, where for example the `Germany` option, I set the value as `https://741.studio/nnroad/germany/`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/css/selectize.default.min.css"
  integrity="sha512-pTaEn+6gF1IeWv3W1+7X7eM60TFu/agjgoHmYhAfLEU8Phuf6JKiiE8YmsNC0aCgQv4192s4Vai8YZ6VNM6vyQ=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/js/selectize.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-IOebNkvA/HZjMM7MxL0NYeLYEalloZ8ckak+NDtOViP7oiYzG5vn6WVXyrJDiJPhl4yRdmNAG49iuLmhkUdVsQ=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>

<select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
  <option value="">Select a state...</option>
  <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/shanghai/">Shanghai</option>
  <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/germany/">Germany</option>
  <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/taiwan/">Taiwan</option>
  <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/singapore/">Singapore</option>
  <!-- just add the rest of options on your own -->
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks didn't notice this, the issue is now sorted :)